# Unit testing blocking processes

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

I have a worker processes working on a data queue. A `training worker` reads and processes data from the `training queue`. It continues to poll and on the look out for new data written to the queue.

I have implemented the worker as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  startTraining()
}

public static boolean startTraining() {
  trainingWorker = new WorkerImpl(config);
  final Thread workerThread = new Thread(trainingWorker);

  WorkerListener listener = new WorkerListener() {
    public void onEvent(WorkerEvent event, Worker worker, String queue, Job job, 
                        Object runner, Object result, Exception ex) {
      if(event.equals(WorkerEvnet.JOB_SUCCESS) {
        //get data
        //process data
        //send data
      }
    }
  }

  trainingWorker.addListener(listener, WorkerEvent.JOB_SUCCESS, WorkerEvent.JOB_FAILURE,
                     WorkerEvent.WORKER_ERROR, WorkerEvent.WORKER_POLL);
  workerThread.start();
  workerThread.join();
}
```

I want unit tests to see if the worker read the data properly, processed it correctly and successfully sent it. The problem is because of `Thread.join()`; the call to the main function never returns (as the worker is suppose to run continuously). In this case should I not write unit tests for it? If yes, how can I write some other form of test that will ensure the worker is working  as desired?

Comment: Do you need the call to `workerThread.join()`? What purpose does it serve? If one thread starts another and immediately joins it, it might as well have done the work itself.

Comment: If I don't do `thread.join()`, the worker process dies..which I don't want as the worker process need to live forever.

Comment: would it be a solution to start the worker in a isolated set up, with a mocked queue? after handling this mocked queue you can stop the worker.

Comment: If the worker thread is a normal thread, then the worker process won't die as long as that thread is running. It's only if that thread is a daemon that the process will die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want either to remove join from your code, or to start new thread from your test case, which will start the worker for you.

Obviously you will need the way to terminate the worker, for version it may look like

```
public void stopWorker() {
 workerThread.interrupt()
}
```

so you will need to convert your **workerThread** local value to a field, and make it **volatile**.